# Integrating a BesselJ integrand to obtain the same result as Maple 16

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I would like to check the following integration:

```
Integrate[y Integrate[1/x BesselJ[1, x Exp[I π/4]] BesselJ[1, x Exp[-I π/4]],
          {x, 0, y}], {y, 0, r}]
```

*Mathematica* 9.0 is not able to evaluate the integral. However, Maple 16 gives the following result:

```
r^4/32 * hypergeometric([1/2],[3/2,3/2,2,2],r^4/64)
```

Is this result correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Mathematica* can do it, but need to use the `HypergeometricPFQ` form, as follows. For some reason, *Mathematica* can't do it in `BesselJ`. May be a report should be send to support@wolfram.com

First to show that the  `HypergeometricPFQ` form is equivalent to the `BesselJ` form:

```
 bad = BesselJ[1, x*Exp[I*Pi/4]]*BesselJ[1, x*Exp[-I*Pi/4]];
 good = 1/4 x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{},{2},-1/4 I x^2] HypergeometricPFQ[{},{2},1/4 I x^2]
 FullSimplify[bad - good]
 (* 0 *)
```

Now the integral works, and gives the result shown by Maple. So Maple is correct :)

```
 WL = Integrate[y*Integrate[1/x*good, {x, 0, y}], {y, 0, r}]
 (* -(1/32) I r^2 Sqrt[-r^4]  HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/2, 3/2, 2, 2}, r^4/64] *)
```

To verify the above is the same as Maple's:

```
maple = 1/32*r^4*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/2, 3/2, 2, 2}, 1/64 r^4];
Grid[Join[{{"r", "WL", "Maple"}}, 
  N@Table[{i, WL /. r -> i, maple /. r -> i}, {i, 0, 10, 1}]]]
```

[image: check Maple's result]

Comment: Hi Naseer, 

Thanks alot for spending your time.

Comment: @Nasser, I am strongly impressed by your answer.

Comment: Hi Naseer, 

Thanks alot for spending your time and clarifying my doubt. 

I would be greatful if you could tell me know how you come up with the equation "good", i.e representing BesselJ in terms of Hypergeometric function. 

I do agree that we can convert the BesselJ interms of Hypergeometric functions. Have you done it manually or Mathematica can do it. I was searching for the command on representing the BesselJ in terms of Hypergeometric series.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thanks :) @ learner123, actually I was just lucky I found it. I was hoping if I can find different form, that will send Integrate into different code path to allow it to do it. So I looked at all the different possible transformations to other special functions from BesselJ, tried few and none worked, and just before I gave up, HypergeometricPFQ worked. I used Maple's nice convert commands to try different forms, then copied each form to Mathematica and tried them to see if it will work or not. That is how I found it.

Comment: Naseer, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the trick making the integration possible is just a change of variable `Exp[-I Pi/4] x -> z`.
Defining :

```
g[z_, y_] = Exp[-I Pi/4] y/z BesselJ[1, z] BesselJ[1, I z]
```

gives

```
Integrate[Integrate[ Exp[I Pi/4] g[z, y], {z, 0, Exp[-I Pi/4] y}], {y, 0, r}]
(* 1/32 r^4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/2, 3/2, 2, 2}, r^4/64] *)
```

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, although *Mathematica* is unable to deal with the integral as it stands, using the [Kelvin functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.61) yields an answer equivalent to the one returned by Maple.

In particular,

```
Integrate[(y/x) (KelvinBer[1, x]^2 + KelvinBei[1, x]^2), {y, 0, r}, {x, 0, y}]
   1/32 r^4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/2, 3/2, 2, 2}, r^4/64]
```

where I used one of the defining relations between Kelvin and Bessel functions given in the DLMF.