# Converting a hypergeometric function to a Bessel function

Tags: special-functions

Is there any way to get a Bessel function equivalent to a Hypergeometric function?

Would it be possible in general?

From Maple integration (as discussed in [Integrating a BesselJ integrand to obtain the same result as Maple 16](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37931)), the result of a symbolic integration is

```
 r^4/32 * hypergeometric([1/2],[3/2,3/2,2,2],r^4/64)
```

Is there any way to represent the above hypergeometric function into an equivalent Bessel function?

Your inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: according to maple, it could not do the above. Not all combination of lower and upper power gives conversion. For example this does: `r^4/32 *  hypergeom([1/2],[3/2,1/2],z^4/64);` giving `(1/32)*r^4*sqrt(Pi)*sqrt(2)*BesselJ(1/2, (1/4*I)*z^2)/sqrt(I*z^2)` but changing the second lower power from 1/2 to 3/2, then it wont. I do not know now how to do these conversions in Mathematica. I have not studied special functions yet at school. Next semester will.

Comment: btw, Mathematica has number of hypergeom, called PFQ, QF1, 1F1, PFQRequalarized. `FunctionExpand[]` can be used on these as per help `Use FunctionExpand to transform HypergeometricPFQ into less general functions` but can't specify the target function like with Maple. For the above example in my comment, it returned `1/8 r^2 Sinh[r^2/4]` for example. See help on FunctionExpand may be there is way.

Comment: Hi Naseer, Thansk for your reply.